# What will the output of this pseudo code be?

Tags: data-structures, stack

If C is a stack, I am trying to figure out what the output of `System.out.println(str);` will be.

I believe that the `System.out.println(str);` command will output `Harry`, but I would like confirmation because I do not fully understand the `.remove()` command.  When I convert this pseudo code into Java, it does not recognize the `.remove()` command unless I pass an integer through it, such as `.remove(2)` for instance.  So I am not sure in this case if `.remove()` is an invalid command, or if it is an appropriate method for a Stack.  My research seems to show that there is no .remove() method applicable to stacks.

So my question is, if C is a stack, what will be the output of `System.out.println(str);`?

```
public interface Container<T>
{
 void insert(T x);  // insert x into Container
  T remove();       // remove item from Container
}

public class C<T> implements Container<T>
{
 public C() { /* constructor */ } 
 public void insert(T x) { /* insert x into C */ }
 public T remove() { /* remove item from C */ }
 //.. other methods
}

Here is a program segment that uses class C above:

Container<String> words = new C<String>();
String w1 = "Tom";
String w2 = "Dick";
String w3 = "Harry";
String w4 = "Moe";
words.insert(w1);
words.insert(w2);
words.insert(w3);
words.insert(w4);
String str = words.remove(); // remove
str = words.remove();        // remove again
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Likely because there are plenty of implementations of stacks out there from which you could see the correct behavior. You would appear to be using a JVM based application which has just such an [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `C` is a regular stack (and it's coded correctly), then it's a LIFO (last in, first out) container.

That means things will come out in the opposite order to which you put them in.

So the first `remove` would give you `Moe`, and the second would give you `Harry`.

In full detail:

```
operation       stack (top,...,bottom)   str
---------       ----------------------   ---
initial state   <empty>
push tom        tom
push dick       dick, tom
push harry      harry, dick, tom
push moe        moe, harry, dick, tom
pop str         harry, dick, tom         moe
pop str         dick, tom                harry
```